# how to make API response from php

Tags: php, json, api, codeigniter

hello I made a post method with the API, I want to make a response like the following what can?

```
 {
    "status": 200,
    "error": false,
    "data": [
        {
            "id_kab": "56",
            "id_prov": "1",
            "kd_kab": "CGK10000"
        }
    ]
}
```

what I did through POSTMAN now results like this

```
{
     "id_kab": "56",
     "id_prov": "1",
     "kd_kab": "CGK10000"
}
```

this my code insert to database

```
     public function submit_post() {
            $data = array(
                'id_kab'        => $this->input->post('id_kab'),
                'id_prov'       => $this->input->post('id_prov'),
                'kd_kab'        => $this->input->post('kd_kab')
            );
            $insert = $this->db->insert('service', $data);
            if ($insert) {
            $arr=array(
            'status'  => 200,
            'message' => 'Success'
            );
             header('Content-Type: application/json');
             echo json_encode($arr,TRUE);
            } else {
                $this->response(array('status' => 'fail', 502));
            }
         }
```

how to change the response? thank you

Comment: You probably don't mean to be adding an `options` parameter to `json_encode()`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I recommend this clean snippet: https://3v4l.org/3aRvg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the response given, data should be given as an array, So please try the below code

```
$output = array();
$data = array();
$data[] = array(
                'id_kab'        => $this->input->post('id_kab'),
                'id_prov'       => $this->input->post('id_prov'),
                'kd_kab'        => $this->input->post('kd_kab')
            );

$output["data"] = $data;
$output["status"] = 200;
$output["error"] = false;
echo json_encode($output); exit;
```

OutPut is as follows

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "error": false,
    "data": [{
        "id_kab": "56",
        "id_prov": "1",
        "kd_kab": "CGK10000"
    }]
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/WBtG1)